# How to scan an unknown number of numbers in Python?

Tags: python, eof

Is there a way to scan an unknown number of elements in Python (I mean scan numbers until the user writes at the standard input eof(end of file))?

Comment: How would this user be asked to input the numbers (command line args or prompting the user or `??`)?

Comment: Please show us, what you have already tried and what's your concrete problem/exception/...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`raw_input` (`input` in Python 3) throws `EOFError` once EOF is reached.

```
while 1:
    try:
        num = int(raw_input("enter a number: "))
    except EOFError:
        break
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you need to process the first number before the second is entered? If not, then `int(s) for s in sys.stdin.read().split()` would probably do, either as a list comprehension (in `[]`) or generator expression (in `()`, for example as a function argument).

Answer (score 0):

This would break at any

Here is one primitive way to do it.

```
In [1]: while True:
   ...:     try:
   ...:         num = int(raw_input())
   ...:     except EOFError:
   ...:         break
   ...:
```

Example output for the input that I had given:

```
10
20
40
50
```

This would break not just for `EOF` but for any input which does not convert to number.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way... sometimes, I use a different programming language called [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)).

There, you can enter:

```
my_variable = scan()
```

...and enter numbers as you wish. Even with copy & paste.

Then, you can dump the input:

```
dump(my_variable, "my_variable.Rdata")
```

`my_variable.Rdata` is a text file which contains an R list... which can be easily converted into a Python list:

```
# a list in R syntax:
my_variable <- c(1, 2, 3)

# a list in Python syntax:
my_variable = [1, 2, 3]
```